# How can I manage SQL Server jobs using a Database project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, database-project, sql-server-agent

Does Visual Studio 2010 support managing SQL Server jobs in the Database Project?

I am working with a database project in Visual Studio 2010. I would like to manage my `database scheduler` job in my database project. It seems that I could not create any server object in the database project.

Answer (score 6):

What we do at my company is:

1. Script out your jobs to be re-runnable (either drop/create or skip if exists)
2. Place the scripts in your Post-Deployment folder (and include the reference in your Script.PostDeployment.sql file as necessary)

Answer (score 1):

No, you won't be able to do that. If you want to use Visual Studio to manage database projects you can use the [database and server projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678491.aspx) (what used to be called Data Dude).

You might also want to take a look at [Red Gate SQL Connect](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-connect/). It works with databases and source control through Visual Studio.